# keep environment when executing in script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have a bash script that should be executing a number of commands. The commands work fine when entered in a termainal but when I try to execute them from inside the script they don't work, so I assume it's something environment-specific.

In the script I have

```
exec "$cmd"
```

and it doesn't work, while if I copy the contents of $cmd and paste in a terminal it works fine.

How do I keep the current environment when running the script? Or do you have any other idea what it might be?

Comment: Running the script does not change the environment by default. You've misdiagnosed the problem.

Comment: Be sure to `export` the variables needed by the script before running it.

Comment: Ingacio: Hmkay, then I don't know.
I do exec "$command" in the script and it doesn't work, the exact same command in the terminal work.

choroba: I'm not sure which variables it is :/ it's a big enterprise environment with scripts and variables all over the place.

Comment: Is there some special reason you are using exec? Why not just write the command directly? e.g.: `cmd=ls; $cmd;'

Comment: I tried both and neither worked, is there any difference?

Comment: I assume @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams' answer is correct, and it should be complete for all use cases. If you are sure that you have no embedded spaces in your arguments you *might* get away with just `exec $cmd` without any double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

[Put the command in an array instead.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

```
arr=(foo bar baz quux)
exec "${arr[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `set -o allexport` at the top of your bash script.  This should automatically export all variables you define.  (Do note that this is considered bad style; a better thing would be to just export the proper variables).

Answer (score -2):

If all the command should be ran from the same dir you can use

```
cd /d $Location
```

at the beginning of the script to set the location for the commands to be ran.

cd -- This is the change directory command.
/d -- This switch makes cd change both drive and directory at once.

if you wanted the command to be ran from say  D:\scripts
with out the /d you would need to

```
D:
cd \scripts
```

but with the above command you can do it in one line

```
cd /d D:\scripts
```

-Edit again-

My apologies, it clearly says BASH but i read it at BATCH for some reason.
will be more careful in the future.

Comment: Downvoted because this answer is obscure, probably you can save it though. Could you explain (by [edit]ing) what `/d` is supposed to mean? Aren't you confusing `cd` of `cmd.exe` with the one of `bash`? Please notify me (@KamilMaciorowski) in a comment to get my attention. I will review the improved answer and I will consider revoking the downvote. (Deleting the answer is also an option, in case you recognize it cannot be improved; but I hope it will be improved).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - edited to explain more.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:bash] but your answer explains `cd` of `cmd.exe`. `cd` in Bash will treat `/d` as a path. On the other hand `$Location` looks like a Bash variable and I guess `cmd.exe` won't understand it. My downvote stands because the answer confuses two different `cd` commands and it's therefore not useful.

Comment: One more thing: please note any answer should match the question; so the right thing to save the answer is to drop everything that refers to `cd` of `cmd.exe` and keep what refers to `cd` of `bash` (not the other way around).